# WIX Error 2716: Couldn't create a random subcomponent name for component 'CopySTST'

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I Am using Heat at run time to generate the components that will installed. There are few files that I need to copy. But every time I use `<CopyFile>` without the FileId attribute, it fails at run time with `Error 2716:  Couldn't create a random subcomponent name for component 'copyFile'`

I can't use FileId because it is not known at the design time.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the output WXS file with XSL template. There's `-t:` switch among heat command line options to do this. In that template, you can add a `CopyFile` elements to the proper components and avoid "Id is unknown" problem you face with.

Answer (score -2):

Use [paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/10/21/wix-a-better-tallow-paraffin.aspx) or custom action

- Paraffin

`%1\Paraffin.exe -dir "..\..\AppFolder" -dirref INSTALLLOC -custom COMPONENTNAME ..\..\ApplicationFragment.wxs -guids -ext .csproj -ext .cs -direXclude obj -direXclude "bin\Config" -direXclude Properties -multiple`

- Custom Action

In customaction add

```
<CustomAction Id="A_SetQtCmdLineCopyFiles" Property="QtExecCmdLine"
                Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /c copy &quot;[INSTALLLOC]AppFolder\FileName&quot; &quot;[TARGETDIR]&quot;" />
<CustomAction Id="QtCmdCopyFiles" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```

Then in Product.wxs add

```
<Custom Action="GA_SetQtCmdLineCopyFiles" After="InstallFinalize">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
<Custom Action="QtCmdCopyFiles" After="GA_SetQtCmdLineCopyFiles">NOT INSTALLED AND NOT REMOVE</Custom>
```

Comment: the custom actions should be used only when there's no other option. It's a so-called "last resort". In this particular way you're suggesting to re-invent the wheel in a very brutal manner :-) Instead, it's usually much better to dig out the exact reason of the problem and fix it. More about custom actions here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2007/04/20/custom-action-guidelines.aspx and here (the intro part): http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/02/08/introducing-lux-declarative-unit-testing-for-custom-actions/